# Meade 4000 'LP' designation

Tags: amateur-observing, optics, eyepiece

[image: Meade 4000 super Plossl 26mm eyepiece]

I have a Meade 4000 super Plossl 26mm eyepiece in front of me with an 'LP' mark on it. I am a fan of the Meade 4000 series, but this is the first time I see this variant.

It looks like it stands for 'low profile', how is this achieved, are the optics any different, or is this just a barrel difference?

More importantly, if one has the choice, is there any advantage to using the LP or plain variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread on Cloudy Nights](https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/83660-similar-meade-plossls-whats-the-difference/) says that LP stands for Low Profile.
Here are two relevant quotes from that link:

> The "LP" was intended for use with the ETX 90, and stands for "Low Profile". As far as I know the barrel length is the only difference.

> The shorter barrel of the LP was made necessary by the narrow focus range of the ETX series refractors.

Comment: `+1` great find!